# How to derive the general Horndeski's action?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, action, modified-gravity

I have seen that [Horndeski's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horndeski%27s_theory) can be written in terms of an action as :
$$
S\left[g_{\mu \nu}, \phi\right]=\int \mathrm{d}^4 x \sqrt{-g}\left[\sum_{i=2}^5 \frac{1}{8 \pi G_{\mathrm{N}}} \mathcal{L}_i\left[g_{\mu \nu}, \phi\right]+\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{m}}\left[g_{\mu \nu}, \psi_M\right]\right]\tag{1}
$$
with the Lagrangian densities
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}_2 & =G_2(\phi, X) \\
\mathcal{L}_3 & =G_3(\phi, X) \square \phi \\
\mathcal{L}_4 & =G_4(\phi, X) R+G_{4, X}(\phi, X)\left[(\square \phi)^2-\phi_{; \mu \nu} \phi^{; \mu \nu}\right] \\
\mathcal{L}_5 & =G_5(\phi, X) G_{\mu \nu} \phi^{; \mu \nu}-\frac{1}{6} G_{5, X}(\phi, X)\left[(\square \phi)^3+2 \phi_{; \mu}^\nu \phi_{; \nu}{ }^\alpha \phi_{; \alpha}{ }^\mu-3 \phi_{; \mu \nu} \phi^{; \mu \nu} \square \phi\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Here $G_N$ is Newton's constant, $\mathcal{L}_m$ represents the matter Lagrangian, $G_2$ to $G_5$ are generic functions of $\phi$ and $X, R, G_{\mu \nu}$ are the Ricci scalar and Einstein tensor, $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the Jordan frame metric, semicolon indicates covariant derivatives, commas indicate partial derivatives, $\square \phi \equiv g^{\mu \nu} \phi_{; \mu \nu}, X \equiv-1 / 2 g^{\mu \nu} \phi_{; \mu} \phi_{; \nu}$ and repeated indices are summed over following Einstein's convention.

I just want to know how we can derive the action (1) and especially the 5 Lagrangian densities $\mathcal{L}_i$ with $i=1,..,5$ ?

Comment: Isn't really there anyone who could detail to how to get these formulas ? Regards